# Plot triple bar graph from a single column grouped by another column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataset.

```
          Country                 Type  Disaster Count
0     CHINA P REP  Industrial Accident             415
1     CHINA P REP   Transport Accident             231
2     CHINA P REP                Flood             175
3           INDIA   Transport Accident             425
4           INDIA                Flood             206
5           INDIA                Storm             121
6   UNITED STATES                Storm             348
7   UNITED STATES   Transport Accident             159
8   UNITED STATES                Flood              92
9     PHILIPPINES                Storm             249
10    PHILIPPINES   Transport Accident              84
11    PHILIPPINES                Flood              71
12      INDONESIA   Transport Accident             136
13      INDONESIA                Flood             110
14      INDONESIA     Seismic Activity              77
```

I would like to make a triple bar chart and the label is based on the column 'Type'. I would also like to group the bar based on the column 'Country'.

I have tried using (with df as the DataFrame object of the pandas library),

```
df.groupby('Country').plot.bar()
```

but the result came out as multiple bar charts representing each group in the 'Country' column.

The expected output is similar to this:
[image: Expected output of the graph. Drawn not to scale]

What are the codes that I need to run in order to achieve this graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways -

```
df.set_index('Country').pivot(columns='Type').plot.bar()
```

[image]

```
df.set_index(['Country','Type']).plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks to your answer, i find that setting the parameter of stacked = true to be more useful too

Comment: @raflieolwen I am glad it helped :-)